# Which brush is suitable for complex shapes or cavity like lipstick or mouth?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

I'm following [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEJ7rBLGohw) tutorial for quick start in character sculpting and modelling for my game prototype, but I'm facing issues for suitable one for certain area.

I could use clay brush for eyes, nose and ears cavity, but what about mouth or lipstick? Many use only Crease brush, but I'm unable to use it effectively. It ends up deforming the mesh!

[image]

Comment: A sculpt is not likely to have a cut.  I'm aware of no tools to make a literal rip in a mesh in sculpt mode.  For use of a sculpt with a game engine, you're likely going to retopo the sculpt, which is basically box modelling and shrinkwrapping to your sculpt, in which case you can use edit mode tools like 'v' rip to rip edges.

Comment: I'd say sculpt mode is a bad way to make a 'quick' character for a game, as game assets need low poly clean topology. You'll probably have to spend some time doing retopology, so I think it would be quicker to create a simple character with 'box modeling'.

Comment: In traditional modelling, I'm wary of curves or creases/bend - they may be hard to do. In sculpt mode maybe I could do prototype teases quickly (Well, that's what I think) and enhance the character later (eliminate unnecessary polygons, group polygons in larger triangles or quadrilaterals if necessary and fix mistakes).

Comment: Try the draw brush while holding down `ctrl` This works with any brush, it gives the "opposite" effect of the brush